# Linear Algebra Contradiction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix, let $ \vec{v}$ be an eigenvector of $A$, and let $ \vec{w}$ *not* be an eigenvector of $A$.

We have: $\vec{w}^{T}A\vec{v}=\langle\vec{w},A\vec{v} \rangle=\langle\vec{w},λ\vec{v} \rangle=\langleλ\vec{w},\vec{v} \rangle $

We also have: $\vec{w}^{T}A\vec{v}=\langle A^T\vec{w},\vec{v} \rangle=\langle A\vec{w},\vec{v} \rangle$, which would seem to imply that $A\vec{w}=λ\vec{w}$, despite the fact that $\vec{w}$ is not an eigenvector.

Can anyone tell me what went wrong here? I have no idea.

Comment: Why would it follow $Aw=\lambda w$?

Comment: $Aw$ has the same inner product with $v$ as $\lambda w$ does. But that doesn't mean it has the same inner product with any vector that $\lambda w$ does.

Comment: $\langle Aw, v\rangle =\langle \lambda w, v\rangle$

Implies $\langle (A-\lambda I)w, v\rangle =0$

From here you can't conclude $Aw=\lambda w$

Here $w, v$ two specific vector!

Comment: It is true that, if $\langle \vec{y}, \vec{x} \rangle = \langle \vec{z}, \vec{x} \rangle$ **for all** $\vec{x}$, then $\vec{y} = \vec{z}$. It's not true if the equation holds true only for some $\vec{x}$. In this case, you are restricting $\vec{v}$ to belonging to the eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ (a different result will be obtained even if you switch to a different eigenspace). Either way, it's not sufficient to conclude that $A \vec{w} = \lambda \vec{w}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll omit the useless arrow to reduce the clutter. If $Av=\lambda v$, we certainly have
$$
w^{T}Av=\langle w,Av\rangle=
\langle w,\lambda v\rangle=
\langle \lambda w,v \rangle
$$
and similarly
$$
w^TAv=w^TA^Tv=\langle Aw,v\rangle
$$
Therefore we conclude that
$$
\langle Aw-\lambda w,v\rangle=0
$$
so $Aw-\lambda w$ is orthogonal to $v$. If $A$ is $n\times n$, with $n>1$, the orthogonal complement of (the subspace generated by) $v$ has dimension $n-1>0$, so it's impossible to conclude that $Aw-\lambda w=0$.

Actually, your assumption that $w$ is not an eigenvector tells you that $Aw-\lambda w\ne0$, which is entirely possible.